# How to make sure a static method/property runs before all other static properties in other classes

Tags: c++

I have some classes in my project with static properties. How could I make one static method that populates a container from which these static properties read data from. How could I make one static method run first before any other static method.How do you which classes static properties get loaded first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to wrap your static object in a getter function, so that it doesn't get created until it is first used.

This way, the order is determined by the design of the program.

An example of this scheme would be the following:

```
class MyClass {
   public:
     static
     MyContainer& GetTheContainer() {
        static MyContainer* fgCon = new MyContainer; // happens at first demand
        return *fgCon; // happens whenever MyClass::GetTheContainer() is called
     }

     static
     SomeObj& GetFromContainerAt(const int i) {
        MyContainer& c = GetTheContainer();
        return c.At(i);
     }
};
```

The rest depends on the design of your program. You could have the other classes fill the container -- as long as they use `GetTheContainer`, you can be sure that the container will be made first. Or you can fill the container on its creation, either by checking if it's empty (if you're sure it will only ever be empty upon creation), or by using a flag system:

```
     MyContainer& GetTheContainer() {
        static MyContainer* fgCon = new MyContainer; // happens at first demand
        static bool isNew = true; // only true the first time
        if (isNew) {
           // fill the container
           isNew = false;
        }
        return *fgCon; // happens whenever MyClass::GetTheContainer() is called
     }
```

You can read more about this scheme at the [C++ Faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html), for example.

Comment: Note that you can use this even if you have a bunch of code that already uses some static object directly. Just find where the static object is declared, replace it with a getter like above, and then use a `#define (GetTheStaticObject()) theOldObjectVariable`. That way, all the objects get replaced with the getter by the precompiler. I've used this trick before and found it quite convenient!

Comment: swap the tokens in the #define - it should read #define theOldObjectVariable (GetTheStaticObject()), but I hate hacking up code silently via the pre-parser.

Comment: Ah you're right, thanks! It's too late for me to edit the comment, though. (As to the precompiler -- I don't want to advocate it too much, but it can be easier than editing hundreds of files...)